# Amazon EC2 VNC Nvidia GPU usage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vnc, graphics-processing-unit, opengl

I have a GPU instance on Amazon Web Services I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

The console show that the drivers are loaded perfectly, see below output

`$nvidia-smi -q | head
==============NVSMI LOG==============`

Timestamp                           : Thu Nov 13 07:11:13 2014
Driver Version                      : 340.29

Attached GPUs                       : 1
GPU 0000:00:03.0
    Product Name                    : GRID K520
    Product Brand                   : Grid

I have installed xcfe4 and installed vncserver, I can login to the vncviewer and see the instance with xcfe4 but the drivers are not getting loaded there.

It is using software rendering and hence I cannot run blender or any OpenGL applications

Please see the output of the glxdemo command, run through the vnc viewer, a green box appears and the following error is spit out

`$glxdemo
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Resize event
Resize event
Redraw event`

I have also uploaded the screenshot here https://i.stack.imgur.com/r68Vh.png

I would like to know is there a way I can enable the drivers for VNC, I have already tried with x11vnc and it did not work, if someone has a better configuration please let me know I will try again.

Kindly help me with this please?

I have read about virtualgl but dont know how to use it and will it be applicable to my case.